# Does Apache FTP client compress files while transfer?

Tags: java, apache, ftp, compression, ftp-client

I have problem where I need to transfer huge files from server to client through FTP which taking lot of time. We are currently using FTPClient available in apache.commons.net library.

So question is - Does FTPClient compress file while transfer? OR Is there any way I fasten the transfer?

Any pointers or related information would be of great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's called Mode Z (or Compressed Transfer Mode).

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(server.getServer());
ftpClient.login(server.getUsername(), server.getPassword());
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.COMPRESSED_TRANSFER_MODE);
```

You can also obviously compress the files on the server side then send them via standard FTP (it should be the same in the end).

Comment: Thank You! One more follow up question - 
What is compression ratio? How much fast it could be? Can you provide any link to refer for this.

Comment: Not sure about the compression ratio using FTPClient. If you want to have more control over the file compression itself I think you should compress them on the server side (there are a lot of java libs doing it out there such as https://code.google.com/p/lz4/) and then upload them via FTP

Comment: @AnwarShaikh: The algorithm is deflate, which is also used in gzip and which is also used for the content-encoding in HTTP. The compression ratio depends of course on the content, but can be 2:1 .. 5:1 for text (like listings) and probably nothing for already compressed data, like PNG images.